# Can you use "whereas" as a substitute for "because"?

Tags: word-choice

I always use "whereas" as a substitute for "because".

Comment: Congratulations! And I always use "congratulations" as a substitute for "do not do that"!

Answer (score 3):

As a conjunction, [whereas](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whereas) means:

1. In contrast; whilst on the contrary.
2. It being the fact that
3. Inasmuch as

As a conjunction, [because](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/because) means:

1. By or for the cause that; on this account that; for the reason that.
2. As known because; as inferred because; as determined because.
3. (obsolete) So that, in order that.

There is *some* overlap between the second meanings of both words. *Whereas* can be used as a synonym for *since*, and so can *because*. I would find it stilted to try and replace *because* with *whereas* even in those situations. The word *whereas* definitely still has a use, especially in the first sense, even if it is now rarely used except as a preamble to resolutions and the like.

Example:

> He came first in the race *because* his brother came in last.

The meaning of the sentence changes if you substitute *whereas*. (Unless they were the only two in the race…)

> He came first in the race *whereas* his brother came in last.

The first sentence says that the second brother caused the first brother to win. The second sentence merely contrasts the first brother's performance with the second. So clearly *because* can't always be substituted with *whereas*.

Comment: +1 for the example. I'm not sure what caused the OP to ask this question: I presumed it was a question about register.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Yes, but</strike> it is a much more formal version and will probably distract the reader unless it is appropriate for the context. You certainly shouldn't "always" use it.

Comment: I would say it’s not just formal, but _legal_. I can’t recall seeing anyone (more or less current) ever using it outside of legal document.

Comment: I would say it has a definite different meaning than *because*, and can only rarely be substituted without change in meaning.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In BrE, *whereas* is certainly not confined to legal usage. It's not uncommon and is used for contrast as defined in ghoppe's answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Was going to add an answer substantiating above comment, but can't as Q is 'on hold'. [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/whereas) specifically differentiates between legal and other uses. [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/whereas?q=whereas) gives the prime meaning as 'contrast' (with an 'everyday' example); and then a subsidiary legal meaning. [Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=whereas&title=21st) gives both meanings.

Comment: I did not mean to imply that ‘whereas’ in itself is legal, but rather that ‘whereas’ in the sense ‘because/seeing as’ is legalese.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use *whereas* in the sense of *because* as they do have one overlapping meaning, but this usage is nearly limited to legal documents and the like where it means "*It being the fact that*", or "in view of the fact that" as [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whereas?show=0&t=1378109930) defines it.

> Whereas you chose to participate in this stupid prank, you will be held responsible as well.

In lower registers *whereas* is (almost) only used as "*in contrast*"; thus, you shouldn't interchange them and stick with *because*.

Comment: What an odd example they have chosen—such a legalese-sounding word used with such a colloquial term as ‘this stupid prank’!

Comment: I've removed my comments on the basis that you've removed the reference to "*only* used in legal documents". OTOH I'm not sure that your revised sentence is consistent in stating you can "use *whereas* in the sense of *because*", but then goes on to say "it means 'It being the fact that', or 'in view of the fact that'". But I don't propose to discuss that further.